# Objective-C NSURL With Non-Alphabetical Characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsurl, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to create an NSURL with special characters like " ","|","-",":", etc. If I have any of these characters in my string the NSURL does not init. What can I do to create an NSURL with these characters? The following does not work:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://google.com?id=|test|"]; //if i remove the | it works.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Problem Description

From the documentation of [[NSURL initWithString]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/initWithString:)

> Initializes an NSURL object with a provided URL string.
>
> - (id)initWithString:(NSString *)URLString
>
> *Parameters - URLString*
>
> The URL string with which to initialize the NSURL object. **This URL
>   string must conform to URL format as described in RFC 2396, and must
>   not be nil.** This method parses URLString according to RFCs 1738 and
>   1808.
>
> *Return Value*
>
> An NSURL object initialized with URLString. If the URL string was
>   malformed, returns nil.
>
> *Discussion*
>
> **This method expects URLString to contain only characters that are
>   allowed in a properly formed URL. All other characters must be
>   properly percent escaped.** Any percent-escaped characters are
>   interpreted using UTF-8 encoding.

### Solution

You need to encode the string as url first. One of the solutions for this is to use
[[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:)[[1]](http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios)

There are other discussion on Stackoverflow about encoding strings to urls:

1. [iOS : How to do proper URL encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652396/ios-how-to-do-proper-url-encoding)
2. [How do I URL encode a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/url-encode-an-nsstring)

Answer (score 3):

you should use the ASCII value of "|" :i.e %7C. You can not directly use these types of special characters.

```
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://google.com?id=%7Ctest%7C"];
```

i hope it will works.

Comment: and u can do one more thing u can use these special characters with  UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is because those are not directly legal characters for a URL.

This is taken from a brilliant answer to an (in effect) related Question on SO: [Which characters make a URL invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid)

"In general URLs as defined by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (see [Section 2: Characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2)) may contain any of the following characters: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=. Any other character needs to be encoded with the percent-encoding (%hh). Each part of the URI has further restrictions about what characters need to be represented by an percent-encoded word."

However in practice, you shouldn't really use commas or square brackets or funky things in a URL - you don't know which browsers will deal with it properly or not. There is absolutely no good reason to use any funky characters in a URL - even if it is a URL to a local file.

Yes, using `NSURL URLWithString` is a better policy for Objective-C, but the main thing to do is stick to the dos and don'ts of URLs.