# Properly Decoding string url for casting in NSURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I am making player which going to support **Google DFP adserver**. The Ad-server has a VAST link which is XML type and contains media-file, track links, clickLink etc...

The clickLinks includes a redirecting url to the original url which I could not properly decode.

The link looks like:
https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/aclk?sa=L&ai=B2JSpRFcKVq_SAsifbr-gqPAE9-CGpQcAAAAQASCPsd4lOABY37Owp4gCYJn-noa4IboBCzYyNHgzNTJfeG1syAEF2gEFaHR0cDqpArGOjXR685U-wAIC4AIA6gIULzEzMTMwMjQwNy9Vem1hbl9Ea3n4AvTRHpADhAeYA4QHqAMB0ASQTuAEAZAGAaAGI9gHAQ&num=0&cid=5Ggrgwo88gHDUD7JBb6uTLxZ&sig=AOD64_0xhsqN4jSnVOZ-eKo9KCVTet61iQ&client=ca-pub-3069068742246799&adurl=http://dkykartal.com/%3Futm_source%3DUzmanTV%26utm_medium%3DVideo_PreRoll%26utm_content%3DDKY_Kartal%26utm_campaign%3DDKY_Kartal_IBillBoard

I tried to decode by using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` and then encode again but NSURL seems to be broken.

Original VastURL is:

https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=624x352&iu=/131302407/Uzman_Dky&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=xml_vast2&unviewed_position_start=1&url=[referrer_url]&description_url=[description_url]&correlator=1443516172

How can properly cast this to an `NSURL`?

Comment: Hi, is it the first or the second URL that's broken?

Comment: I think second url seems to be broken

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652396/ios-how-to-do-proper-url-encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, url relies on CDATA thats why it could not decode/encode properly. I used - `(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock{` delegation method and encoded the string like this:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Than I assigned to NSURL without any problem.

Answer (score 5):

Read your question again, carefully. You say you want to decode the URL and call a method that's called

```
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding
        ^^^^^^
```

Try using `stringByRemovingPercentEncoding`. This should decode your URL.

To the other question, how to "cast" it to NSURL: Casting means you are forcing the debugger to treat a variable like a specific type. Meaning you cannot cast an object and turn it into an instance of another type.

You have to create an instance of NSURL *using* a string:

`NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[URLString stringByRemovingPercentEncoding]];`

Comment: so NSURL will accept decoded URL or do i have to encode it again?

Comment: URL encoding is only needed in browsers. In a "real electronic world" you would never need no escaping. `URLWithString` converts a string into URL. Thats it. Don't think of "lets do as much as can for the computer, he is too stupid anyway". Remember; you are developing for an Apple platform. Use it as you would do in real life. Don't think of abstractions like encoding. Apple will do it all for you!

Comment: Julian thank you for your help. I successfully Decoded URL but there's  something not going well for decoding operation. I just wrote down on gist which my original Vast Link ( coming from xml ) , Decoded URL (Not working redirection occured).  the method that i've changed :
https://gist.github.com/onderozcan/6493f337a9c1dea8058d

Comment: Can we discuss this in the chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91877/discussing-properly-decoding-string-url-for-casting-in-nsurl

Comment: sure i joined, and wrote something in. Pls check it @Julian

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentsSeparatedByString`.

Example:

```
NSString* url = @"https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=624x352&iu=/131302407/Uzman_Dky&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=xml_vast2&unviewed_position_start=1&url=[referrer_url]&description_url=[description_url]&correlator=1443516172";

NSArray* components = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
for (NSString* str in components)
{
    NSArray* keyval = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    // keyval[0] is your key
    // keyval[1] is your value
    NSLog(@"key: %@ | value: %@", keyval[0], keyval[1]);
}
```

Example output:

```
 key: https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz | value: 624x352
 key: iu | value: /131302407/Uzman_Dky
 key: impl | value: s
 key: gdfp_req | value: 1
 key: env | value: vp
 key: output | value: xml_vast2
 key: unviewed_position_start | value: 1
 key: url | value: [referrer_url]
 key: description_url | value: [description_url]
 key: correlator | value: 1443516172
```

The URLs you got, can be decoded by `stringByRemovingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`, to remove all escape sequences.

Comment: So what my steps going to be ?

1. Seperating URI by components and adding in to Array
2. Decode each component with  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding
3. concat all components and create new NSString
4. Cast NSString in to NSURL urlWithString:

Are these true steps? 

Regards

Comment: I just tried to create method but output of URL not working correctly. Here is the gist link that you can easily read my code. Thank you again:

https://gist.github.com/onderozcan/0a11c3b1c55ba2e258b1

Comment: What is not working correctly? What are your issues?

Comment: check the link that i provided gist.github.com

Comment: Yes I've seen that, what are your issues?

Comment: The encoded NSURL output is totaly wrong could you check the output URL and original URL strings?

Comment: have u tried to encode and cast NSURL , it does not.